# Arrays at runtime using opengl-es

Tags: android, arrays, opengl-es, porting

I'm using [this tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/) to work out some stuff, but i'm having to port the code because its in OpenGL instead of GL-ES.  One problem I'm having is setting the arrays because android doesn't seem to support this kind of array

eg:

```
GLint viewport[4];
```

Correct me if I'm wrong and this type of array is supported or enlighten me as to how I should be setting arrays

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this - [Android: 3D with OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)

There is no  GLint type. For that example use:

```
public abstract void glGetIntegerv (int pname, IntBuffer params)

public abstract void glGetIntegerv (int pname, int[] params, int offset)
```

So, you just need to use something like this:

```
int[] viewport = new int[4];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
```

Comment: I'm guessing gl.glGetDoublev isn't supported =( any alternatives?

Comment: I suppose that you should use `glGetInteger` and integer data type instead of the double one... or use float data type and `GL11.glGetFloatv`
I think this procedures are interchangeable. See: [glGet](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, Android just as Java doesn't support declaring arrays this way, this is c/c++ like (static) declaration. I'm guessing you would have to declare array like this:

```
GLint viewport[] = new GLint[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Nehe tutorials are great, but not geared towards Android.  Check out [insanitydesign.com](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/), they ported a bunch of the Nehe tutorials so you don't have to!

And as an aside, there are several great OpenGL tutorials written specifically for Android (like [this one at jayway.com](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/)), why don't you use one of those to get your feet wet?